# Can antifreeze damage exterior paint?

Tags: coolant, paint

For some background, I was driving my 2010 Mustang behind a pickup truck and all of a sudden there was a TON of smoke and liquid on my windshield/hood. I was lucky to not crash.

My best guess is his radiator blew up and the liquid all over my car was coolant. I'm certainly not a mechanic so I could be way off here.

My concern is I wasn't able to get to a car wash until about 3 hours after the fact. Everything *looks* fine but I'm worried it may have done some damage.

Comment: If your car is waxed occasionally, the diluted coolant - I expect that that is what it is - wouldn't have been on there long enough to damage anything.

Comment: As a natural cynic, I assume that because every car windscreen wash additive supplier says "yes it does, if you put it in the washer bottle the resale value of your car will fall to zero, so you MUST buy our super-expensive product instead," the correct answer is "no it doesn't". But I might be wrong, of course :)